# Genesys Engage On-Premise data to cloud

Tags: genesys, genesys-platform-sdk

Genesys PureCloud provides "Notifications APIs" to register a communication channel to receive async events over a WebSocket. Similarly can we have a async WebSocket created for On-Premise deployment of Genesys Engage?

I want to send the data generated in the On-Premise deployment to cloud server for further  processing, is this supported in Genesys Engage?